# Firewalld takes a long time

Tags: boot, systemd, firewalld

I've found that `firewalld` takes a long time in Fedora 24:

```
# systemd-analyze --no-pager blame
         12.051s firewalld.service
          7.613s dev-sda8.device
          6.347s akmods.service
          5.832s dev-sdb3.device
          3.956s systemd-udev-settle.service
          3.561s ldconfig.service
          3.435s lvm2-monitor.service
          3.037s upower.service
          2.983s lm_sensors.service
          2.895s systemd-logind.service
          2.850s akmods-shutdown.service
          2.847s gssproxy.service
          2.847s sysstat.service
          2.841s rsyslog.service
          2.801s rtkit-daemon.service
          2.695s systemd-hwdb-update.service
          1.988s dnf-makecache.service
          1.783s systemd-udevd.service
          1.777s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-623D\x2d6AE0.service
          1.705s systemd-modules-load.service
          1.584s home.mount
          1.472s fedora-readonly.service
          1.457s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
          1.456s proc-fs-nfsd.mount
          1.448s primage.mount
          1.209s plymouth-start.service
          1.144s systemd-fsck-root.service
          1.132s abrtd.service
          1.050s systemd-vconsole-setup.service
          1.040s systemd-sysctl.service
```

Critical chain is as follows:

```
    The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @29.297s
└─multi-user.target @29.296s
  └─crond.service @29.186s
    └─systemd-user-sessions.service @29.060s +100ms
      └─remote-fs.target @29.048s
        └─remote-fs-pre.target @29.048s
          └─iscsi-shutdown.service @29.047s
            └─network.target @29.046s
              └─NetworkManager.service @28.444s +601ms
                └─network-pre.target @28.434s
                  └─firewalld.service @16.383s +12.051s
                    └─dbus.service @13.557s
                      └─basic.target @13.531s
                        └─sockets.target @13.531s
                          └─dbus.socket @13.531s
```

What could I do in order to reduce the startup time of firewalld?